# Best way to parse AlphaNumeric string, parts of which will be converted to Int, Bool, String

Tags: c#, .net, parsing

I have a schema according to which AlphaNumeric string of specific length will be interpreted. For example, index 0-12 interpret as `string`, 13-20 interpreted as `Int`, 21-22 as `Bool` and so on.
So far, I have a linked list that is formed at runtime, where each element(`struct`) has two fields: length and type(`enum`). By iterating through the list and checking which type the element belongs to, correct conversion is performed.
It seems like my method very inefficient and error prone to this task. Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: Please post your method code

Comment: Can you change `AlphaNumeric` format? Then use serialization. If position is known, then simple `Substring`+`Parse` will do the best.

Comment: What is the string in the first place? it sounds like making an object might be a much better option than fabricated strings

Comment: All code is error-prone. The solution is to write unit tests that fully exercise the method to ensure it works as expected.

Comment: @Sinatr what do you mean by `Can you change AlphaNumeric format?`

Comment: Where do you get this string? If you generate it, then instead of position-based string containing values you may use `xml` or `json`. There are methods to serialize/deserialize complete data structures, which completely removes necessity to parse anything (and to convert it to string in first place).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are stuck with a fixed-width data source (which you should avoid if at all possible as they are extremely non human-readable), I would use attributes to directly decorate the class to which the data will be deserialized. Something like:

```
class SomeDTO
{
    [Position(0,12)]
    public string SomeString { get; set; }

    [Position(13, 20)]
    public int SomeInt { get; set; }

    [Position(21-25)]
    public bool SomeBool { get; set; }
}
```

And then write a deserializer that picks up the type from the property directly and the column position from the attribute. That way, all the information for deserializing is kept in one place, reducing risks of typo errors.

Comment: Reflection vs hard-coded numbers. Flexibility vs speed... Could be an option to **deserialize arrays** though (because reflection can be used just once = small overhead).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with David Arno answer and you can try something like below as well.  You can write [extension method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021498/problem-with-substring-argumentoutofrangeexception) if you feel Substring() may through an exception.

```
    string abc = "HelloWorld!!1234567true";            
    int y;
    bool z ;

    string x = abc.Substring(0, 12); 
    Int32.TryParse(abc.Substring(12, 7), out y);
    Boolean.TryParse(abc.Substring(19, 4), out z); 

    Console.WriteLine(x);
    Console.WriteLine(y);
    Console.WriteLine(z);
```