# Updating an existing List using Linq in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list and data as follows.

```
public class Test
{
 public int Id {get;set;}
 public string Name {get;set;}
 public string Quality {get;set;}
}

Test test = new Test();
//db call to get test data
//test = [{1,'ABC','Good'},{2,'GEF','Bad'}]
```

I have to modify the list such that `Name` should be only the first 2 characters and `Quality` should be the first letter.

Expected Output:

```
//test = [{1,'A','G'},{2,'GE','B'}]
```

I tried to achieve with Linq `foreach` as follows. But I am not sure to write conditional statements inside forloop within Linq which resulted in error.

```
test.ForEach(x=> return x.Take(1))
```

Comment: You could override `ToString` function inside `Test` class, In that function you could substring all fields as u wish, and return a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`List.ForEach` is not LINQ though

```
test.ForEach(t => { t.Name = t.Name.Length > 2 ? t.Name.Remove(2) : t.Name; t.Quality = t.Quality.Length > 1 ? t.Quality.Remove(1) : t.Quality; });
```

Better would be to simply call a method that does this.

```
test.ForEach(Modify);
```

---

```
private static void Modify(Test t)
{
    // ,,,
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use simply use [String.Substring](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring(v=vs.110).aspx) as follows:

```
test.ForEach(s =>
{
    s.Name = s.Name.Substring(0, 2);
    s.Quality = s.Quality.Substring(0, 1);
});
```

Thanks, **@Tim** for pointing out that if `Name` or `Quality` is short then this code throws an exception. See [Problem with Substring() - ArgumentOutOfRangeException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021498/problem-with-substring-argumentoutofrangeexception) for the possible solutions for that.